# Delete or reset javascript object

Tags: javascript, mootools

OK I have a list of products that you can add and delete from using javascript.
The problem is that I have this singleselect class that is used for highlighting selected products. whenever  I add or remove a product to the list I want to reset or recreate this singleselect object.
I have searched and I think I understand why the object isn't reseted but I am not sure how to fix it.

My javascript code, this code works but after I remove a product and select another product
I get an error which shows that the old singleselect object still exists.

```
var single;

document.addEvent('domready', function() {      
        setSingleSelect();  
}       

  $('removeProduct').addEvent('click',function(e){
        e.stop();           
        $('productList').getElements('input[value="' + removeElement + '"], div[id="' + removeElement + '"]').destroy();
         single = null;
         setSingleSelect();
    });

function setSingleSelect(){
    single = new SingleSelect(
    $('productList').getElements('div'),
    {onSelectChange : function(element) {       
        removeElement = element.id;                         
    }});    
}
```

Comment: your new instance will overwrite the running one in the reference so essentially the old one may go for garbage collection, unless there are events attached, pointing to the instance, such as DOM events - in which case, it won't. it may be better to review the `SingleSelect` class and simply add some methods for a destructor that deal with removing events and elements and then call the initialize on to the new one. contain your logic within a single instance and its events rather than spread across multiple anon funcs, you are reducing the chances of easy gc. reuse objects!

Comment: Can you post some code for the "SingleSelect", or refer to were to find it?